# I want access the current page url in Groovy and access the variables passed in the url

Tags: groovy

I want access the current page url in Groovy and access the variables passed in the url .

Current Page URL : 
https://sandbox.com?actionid=1&actionDefnId=3217&caseType=61&tenantName=test&nid=12345

I want to access and capture nid in my script

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you face any specific problem?

Comment: I am not able get any function to get any function to access current page url. I am trying below code.

Comment: def data = new URL(feedUrl).getText()

Comment: groovy current page url? are you in grails?